# In a sequence of 0 and 1, how to make sure that no same values appear more than 2 times consecutively?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sequence

I am generating a sequence of equal number of 0's and 1's . A = [ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0] My goal is to not have either 0 or 1 be repeated more than 2 times consecutively. in the above array A, you can see that 1 1 1 appears so somehow I need to switch it around so that one of them becomes 0 and if there is something like 0 0 0 then switch one of them to 1. I have tried few algorithms which work for few iterations but then I get different number of 0's and 1's. Also, the result or the output should maintain the same number of 1's and 0's i.e. six 0's and six 1's.

```
nums = mod( reshape(randperm(1*12), 1, 12), 2)
    for i = 1:length(nums)-2
    if nums(i+1)==nums(i) & nums(i+2) ==nums(i) 
       if nums(i) == 1
      nums(i+2) = 0;
    else
      nums(i+2) = 1;
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: What error? What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I don't get any error while running your code..

Comment: Yes, it doesn't give an error, my bad for saying that. But what I mean to say is that on few iterations, I can get the same number of 1's and 0's but eventually it runs into a sequence where either 1's or 0's are more than the other

Comment: Wait, you mean you must have the same number of ones and zeros at the end of the process? This is a comletely different question

Comment: Yes it should retain the same number of 0's and 1's, that is the whole point. I will make an edit for it in the main post

Comment: How big will be your output in a real case scenario?

Comment: for now the the initial sequence created in 12x1 out of which there are 6 1's and 6 0's. after doing the whole manipulation, it should still end up to be the same size just with the constraints we are trying to randomize it with

Comment: So it will be only and always be a vector with 12 elements?

Comment: yes exactly it has to a vector of 12 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your constraints are too intricated in order to solve the problem *a posteriori*, I'd suggest you to iterate until you find a solution. (This approach being possible considering the small length of your output vector).

**The code would look like :**

```
out=0;

while ~out

    nums = mod( reshape(randperm(1*12), 1, 12), 2);

    diff1=diff(nums);

    diff1(diff1~=0)=NaN;

    diff2=diff(diff1);

    if all(diff2~=0)

        out=1;

    end

end
```

It basically iterates over 2 steps :

**1/ Generate a candidate :**

```
nums = mod( reshape(randperm(1*12), 1, 12), 2);
```

**2/ Check if the candidate respects the constraints**

```
diff1=diff(nums);

diff1(diff1~=0)=NaN;
```

Here MATLAB's `diff` function is used in order to check for repeated numbers. A 0 means that a number is repeated 2 times. In order to check if a number is repeated 3 times we need to use this function a second time.

```
diff2=diff(diff1);
```

Now, a 0 will appear if a number has been repeated 3 times or more consecutively, thus we check the presence of 0's in `diff2`. If there isn't any the candidate is kept and we end the while loop.

```
if all(diff2~=0)

    out=1;

end
```

**Example run :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I was thinking as well, didn't apply it due to the computation time, however, the way your algorithm is set up, it is quite fast than what I was doing. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it corresponds to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make a counter.

```
    nums = mod( reshape(randperm(1*12), 1, 12), 2)
    idx=1;
    counter_one=0;
    counter_zero=0;
    changedIndex=0;

    while idx <= length(nums)
        if (nums(idx) == 0)
            counter_zero = counter_zero+1;
            counter_one=0;
            if (counter_zero == 3)
                nums(idx)=1;
                counter_zero=0;
                changedIndex = 1;
            end
        else
            counter_one= counter_one+1;
            counter_zero=0;
            if (counter_one== 3)
                nums(idx)=0;
                counter_one=0;
                changedIndex =1;
            end
        end

    if (changedIndex == 1)
     if (idx < length(nums))
       if (nums(idx+1)) == 1
          counter_one = 1;
          changedIndex = 0;
       else
          counter_zero=1;
          changedIndex = 0;
       end
    else
           if (nums(idx)) == 1
          counter_one = 1;
          changedIndex = 0;
       else
          counter_zero=1;
          changedIndex = 0;
       end
    end
    end
idx = idx+1;
end
```

I have tested it just now and it worked fine[image]

New test, with a more difficult vector

[image]

Comment: yes you are right, I ran it and didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This doesn't work as stated, although it would work with some modifications : 1/ (A typo) : Either you use `else` instead of `else if` or you'll have to add an `end` in order for it to work. 2/ You have to reset your counter (say counter_zero for example) when the other number occurs

Comment: I ran the code: the sequence generated was [1     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1] . When it goes goes through the while loop, the following output was generated: [1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0] . so it didn't fix the issue. although the code replaced 1 with 0 but now there are three 0's consecutively

Comment: I'm posting an answer

Comment: This should work.. I don't see where it might fail! @BillBokeey thanks for the edit

Comment: AH Ok I know where it might end up an error! It's in the case that the new number is 0 or 1, the counter forgets one!

Comment: Be careful though, this code won't necessarily keep an equal number of 1's and 0's

Comment: I don't think so, (Plus you'll exceed matrix dimensions when `idx==length(nums)` on the line `if (nums(idx+1)) == 1`)

Comment: Yeah only in that situation. But that's easy to overcome - just changed the while cycle

Comment: @BillBokeey yes you are right it exceeds at (nums(idx+1)) == 1)

Comment: Now it won't exceed. @DushyantDhundara

Comment: I don't see how it fixes the problem of having the same amount of 0's and 1's

Comment: yeah it is still running into the problem that numbers are getting repeated. Could you try and run few iterations of it? and when  run the code it says atleast one end is missing @16per9

Comment: @DushyantDhundara done! The problem was the idx=idx+1 got stuck inside the final if cycle. It is working now ;)

Comment: Try with `nums=[1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]`

Comment: nums =

     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0

>> num2=test(nums)

num2 =

     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0

Comment: 5 1's and 7 0's in the output it seems

Comment: I named the function test @BillBokeey

Comment: No it's not.. It doens't output a result with the same amount of 1's and 0's, as stated in OP's question, see example I gave

Comment: LOL ok. That's only dependent of the input vector nums. The code has nothing to do with that section - that's the input - the code is fully set and going to find 3 consecutive number's and change the last index. That's the main point.

Comment: As stated in OP's question : `Also, the result or the output should maintain the same number of 1's and 0's i.e. six 0's and six 1's.`

Comment: @16per9 : if I pick the input vector then that defeats the whole purpose of randomizing the sequence. Otherwise my original code was already producing the right results...I hope that makes sense.. maybe?

Comment: Ok. So in the end just count the number of 1's and 0's, their final position and make changes in order to have that exact number of indexes.

Comment: @DushyantDhundara after 13.00 pm I'll do that.

Comment: @16per9 perhaps you should delete your answer until it is correct... then undelete it when it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way that does not require trying permutations until you find one:

```
A = [];
N = 100; %//number of elements you desire in A (must be even).
```

Initialize A to have equal number of alternating `0s` and `1s`:

```
%//initialize A = [1 0 1 0 1 0....] with equal numbers of 0 and 1.
for x=1:N/2 
    A = [A 1 0];
end
```

Iterate through `A`:

```
for x=3:(N-1) %//iterate through A, and decide to swap or not at each iteration

    if ( A(x) == A(x-1) && A(x) == A(x-2) ) %//must swap
        temp = A(x);
        A(x) = A(x+1);
        A(x+1) = temp;
    elseif ( A(x+1) == A(x-1) && A(x+1) == A(x-2) ) %//must not swap

    else %//can choose to swap or not
        if (randi([0 1])) %should I swap?
            temp = A(x);
            A(x) = A(x+1);
            A(x+1) = temp;
        end
    end

end
```